# AJAX + JSON + PHP

Tags: ajax, php, json

Есть скрипт. Отправка запроса посредством аджакса на сервер. Оттуда приходит джсоном результат и все хорошо работает.

Но если обратится к этому скрипту постом без аджакса, — вываливается просто джсон строка в браузер.

Как бы сделать так, чтоб при отправки аджаксом пост данных, и без него работало одинаково?

Comment: @Dima Logginoff, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**проверяй при выводе:**

```
//обработка запроса...
$data = array(...);

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])&&
  (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])=='xmlhttprequest')){
    //ajax
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($data);
}  else {  
    //no ajax
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    //вывод html страницу с включёнными в неё $data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод.

```
....
создаем результат запроса
....
Проверяем Если запрос AJAX -то отправляем JSON обект, Иначе отправляем как html страницу (тут ее придется еще дособрать с общим шаблоном)
```

Соответственно заголовки до проверки отправлять нельзя, так как они разные.